# How to match this string in bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I'm reading a file in bash, line by line. I need to print lines that have the following format:

don't care <<< at least one character >>> don't care.

These are all the way which I have tried and none of them work:

```
   if [[ $line =~ .*<<<.+>>>.* ]]; then
      echo "$line"
   fi
```

This has incorrect syntax

These two have correct syntax don't work

```
   if [[ $line =~ '.*<<<.+>>>.*' ]]; then
      echo "$line"
   fi
```

And this:

```
   if [[ $line == '*<<<*>>>*' ]]; then
      echo "$line"
   fi
```

So how to I tell bash to only print lines with that format? PD: I have tested and printing all lines works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For maximum compatibility, it's always a good idea to define your regex pattern as a separate variable in single quotes, then use it unquoted. This works for me:

```
re='<<<.+>>>'
if [[ $line =~ $re ]]; then
    echo "$line"
fi
```

I got rid of the redundant leading/trailing `.*`, by the way.

Of course, I'm assuming that you have a valid reason to process the file in native bash (if not, just use `grep -E '<<<.+>>>' file`)

Answer (score 2):

Don't need regular expression. filename patterns will work just fine:

```
if [[ $line == *"<<<"?*">>>"* ]]; then ...
```

- `*` - match zero or more characters
- `?` - match exactly one character
- `"<<<"` and `">>>"` - literal strings: The angle brackets need to be quoted so bash does not interpret them as a here-string redirection.

```
$ line=foobar
$ [[ $line == *"<<<"?*">>>"* ]] && echo y || echo n
n
$ line='foo<<<>>>bar'
$ [[ $line == *"<<<"?*">>>"* ]] && echo y || echo n
n
$ line='foo<<<x>>>bar'
$ [[ $line == *"<<<"?*">>>"* ]] && echo y || echo n
y
$ line='foo<<<xyz>>>bar'
$ [[ $line == *"<<<"?*">>>"* ]] && echo y || echo n
y
```

Answer (score 1):

`<`, `<<`, `<<<`, `>`, and `>>` are special in the shell and need quoting:

```
[[ $line =~ '<<<'.+'>>>' ]]
```

`.` and `+` shouldn't be quoted, though, to keep their special meaning.

You don't need the leading and trailing `.*` in `=~` matching, but you need them (or their equivalents) in patterns:

```
[[ $line == *'<<<'?*'>>>'* ]]
```

It's faster to use grep to extract lines:

```
grep -E '<<<.+>>>' input-file
```

Comment: Actually, I'm surprised the parser recognizes them as redirection operators inside `[[`, since you can't run a command in that context.

Comment: @chepner: I don't know, but I think there are several phases of parsing, splitting into commands and redirections is the very first one, maybe the parsing of `[[...]]` happens too late.

Comment: Good point. The tokenizer recognizes the operator before the parser recognizes the conditional command. It's not something like expansion, which occurs after the parser has recognized `[[` as a command, that can be disabled based on context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't even understand why you are reading the file line per line. I have just launched following command in the bash prompt and it's working fine:

```
grep "<<<<.+>>>>" test.txt
```

where test.txt contains following data:

```
<<<<>>>>
<<<<a>>>>
<<<<aa>>>>
```

The result of the command was:

```
<<<<a>>>>
<<<<aa>>>>
```

Comment: Between `<<<` and `>>>` should be _at least_ one character. Not exactly one.

Comment: Now the "result of the command" in your answer is wrong ;) And also - it should be `<<<.+>>>` to match the pattern from question (not `<<<<.+>>>>`)